# C# RichTextBox selection not working when window not focused

Tags: c#, focus, richtextbox, selection

So I have simple Windows application with RichTextBox component on form. The problem is when the form losts focus (notepad.exe runs near by on desktop) and then i click RichTextBox for selecting text - nothing happens, except form gets focus. The second click, when the form is already focused, works fine and text are now selected. The same problem with LinkClicked event in RichTextBox - it works only when clicked twice. How to change this behavior?

Comment: found a good answer in a similar thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47635568/6656775

Answer (score 0):

Try to use mouse_Click:

```
richTextBox1_mouseClick(...)
{
    if(e.Buttons == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        richTextBox1.Select();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not what i meant. I just want to change the selection when form is in unfocused state, i.e. "MouseDown"->"MouseMove"->"MouseUp", but richTextBox is not reacting on this. TextBox component allow to do this, richTextBox - does not.